# Is there a way to call data (url) from extension storage in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, data-retrieval

I am trying to call a url from extension storage to send it to a server for analysis but I cant seem to find a straight forward solution to this. is there somthing I am missing?

Any help would be great

Edit:

I have attached a photo of the code which is sending a url to the extension storage. It is storing the url but is there a way to then send this data else where or a way to print it with in the extension interface?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC6ai.png)

Comment: It's impossible to help currently. Please add [MCVE](/help/mcve) and/or more specific details.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.